# Trying to insert Parent-Child records with loose relationship

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, database-design, ssis

I have several tables that are used to reduce natural keys into surrogate keys.

```
CREATE TABLE Mapping.RelatedData
(
    Id INT IDENTITY NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    DataSetId INT NOT NULL REFERENCES DataSet (Id),
    DataTypeId INT NOT NULL REFERENCES DataType (Id)
)

CREATE TABLE Mapping.RelatedDataForA
(
    RelatedDataId INT NOT NULL REFERENCES Mapping.RelatedData (Id),
    NatrualColumn1 INT NOT NULL,
    NatrualColumn2 INT NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE Mapping.RelatedDataForB
(
    RelatedDataId INT NOT NULL REFERENCES Mapping.RelatedData (Id),
    NatrualColumn3 INT NOT NULL,
    NatrualColumn4 INT NOT NULL
)

-- Several other tables for C, D, E, etc..
```

This way I can have separate tables

```
CREATE TABLE HeaderFormattedData
(
    Id INT IDENTITY NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    RelatedDataId INT NOT NULL REFERENCES Mapping.RelatedData (Id)
    DataKey INT NOT NULL
    -- Other columns
)

CREATE TABLE LinesFormattedData
(
    Id INT IDENTITY NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    RelatedDataId INT NOT NULL REFERENCES Mapping.RelatedData (Id),
    DataKey VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    LineId INT NOT NULL
    -- Other columns
)
```

That have a unified relationship to `RelatedData`. Otherwise I would need a separate Header/Line table for each `RelatedData` table. This data eventually get aggregated into one table and having separate `RelatedData` tables would mean either separate columns with strong relationships or a single column with no relationship.

I am using SSIS to insert my data and this table scheme is leading to an RBAR (row by agonizing row) method to insert the parent then insert the child. I could create a view and use an instead of trigger to simplify it, but is there a better way to insert the records or is this a symptom of bad table design?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible solution I am using is a concatenation of the unique data as the source identifier.

```
CREATE TABLE Mapping.RelatedData
(
    Id INT IDENTITY NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    DataSetId INT NOT NULL REFERENCES DataSet (Id),
    DataTypeId INT NOT NULL REFERENCES DataType (Id),
    SourceId NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
);
```

Inside my SSIS package I can create a derived column with the concatinated data.

Expression:

```
((DT_WSTR,10)NatrualColumn1) + ((DT_WSTR,10)NatrualColumn2)
```

I inserted the data with the derived column into an intermediary table.

I then followed this process described in [Insert Parent and Child Tables with SSIS Part 2](http://agilebi.com/jwelch/2010/10/29/insert_parent_child_pattern2/).

- Create a data flow task to insert the parent records
- Create a data flow task to lookup the parent identifier and insert the child record